# Find position of vowels in a string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to work on some Python code where a person is prompted to input a string of text. Then I need to find the position of all of the vowels in the string. I have this, but it's not working...

```
userInput = (input("Enter a line of text: ")
vowels = ("aeiouAEIOU")
position = 0
for char in userInput :
    if char in vowels :
        position = userInput.find(vowels)
        print(char, position)
```

It returns the vowels but gives each position as -1. What am I doing wrong? I have read that the index function could be used, but we're not getting to that for a few more weeks. Any suggestions on simple fixes I could make to this code? Thank you!!

Comment: Your code needs rethinking. you're checking each character in the input string to see if it contains 'aeiouAEIOU' I think you have something the wrong way around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the test `char in vowels` is verified, you are currently reading a letter `char` that **is a vowel**, at that point you can output it directly. On the other hand you need to remember the position by incrementing it every time you move to the next `char`:

```py
userInput = "This is some input from the user"
vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
position = 0
for char in userInput:
    if char in vowels:
        print(char, position)
    position += 1
```

This code can be improved to be a bit more pythonic, using `enumerate` can save you from keeping track of the position by hand:

```py
serInput = "This is some input from the user"
vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
for position, char in enumerate(userInput):
    if char in vowels :
        print(char, position)
```

Another improvement can be made, this time we can improve performances. Time cost of checking `char in vowels` is proportional to the size of the string `vowels`. On the other hand you can change the type of `vowels` from `string` to `set`, checking if an item is part of a set is done in constant time:

```py
userInput = "This is some input from the user"
vowels = set("aeiouAEIOU")
for pos, char in enumerate(userInput):
    if char in vowels:
        print(char, pos)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code has the mistake that when you do `userInput.find(vowels)` remember that the string `vowels` is `"aeiouAEIOU"` so it will not find that unless the either string `"aeiouAEIOU"` is in `userInput`. Instead, it is best to `enumerate` and return those indexes.

```
userInput = input("Enter a line of text: ")
vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
for i, char in enumerate(userInput):
    if char in vowels:
        print(char, i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a list comprehension and enumerate:

```
positions = [i for i, char in enumerate(userInput) if char in vowels]
```

This will give you a list of the indices of vowels - it enumerates your user input string as a list of characters with an index, and applies a predicate- in this case if the character is a vowel or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
string find(str,str, beg=0, end=len(string))
```

method determines if string str occurs in string, or in a substring of string if starting index beg and ending index end are given. In your code，`userInput.find(vowels)` it would check the userInput if it contains the whole bunch of vowels which is "aeiouAEIOU". so the code can be improved as follow:

```
userInput = (input("Enter a line of text: ")
vowels = ("aeiouAEIOU")
position = 0
for char in userInput :
    if char in vowels :
        position = userInput.find(char)
        print(char, position)
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind but I cleaned up your answer. The best way to format code is to paste it in and click the `{}` button to format it. Edit it again if you want to get rid of my name as editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, it's similar to yours:

```
 userInput = input("Enter a line of text: ")
 vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"

 for count in userInput:
     x = 9 #there are 10 vowels, from 0 to 9
     while x >= 0:
         if count == vowels[x]:
             print("\n",count)
         x -= 1

 print("\n Done")
```